# VNC not able to show desktop when legacy camera is enabled

Tags: camera, vnc, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

When I connect via VNC viewer to my PI4 I get the screen: cannot currently show desktop. I tried changing the resolution for VNC in the raspi-config with no luck. The problem started occurring after I enabled the legacy camera option, and then disappeared when I disabled it.

Any ideas?

OS bullseye

Comment: this link solved the same problem for me successfully https://www.shellhacks.com/raspberry-pi-force-hdmi-hotplug/

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer this question, but uncommenting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in `/boot/config.txt` then rebooting solved it for me. You can edit config.txt with `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`.

Comment: I downgraded my OS to Legacy OS (Buster) and the same problem happened there when I enabled the camera (which isn't labelled Legacy Camera in that OS). The same fix worked in this OS.

Comment: For what its worth, this also worked for me even though i have no HDMI connected and am running headless. Seems like some kind of strange bug.